# how to add var to the response object

Tags: javascript, axios, discord.js

If I have this

`let bitcoinval = response.data.bpi.USD.rate`

and I just want it to get the `USD` as a variable from in the function how would I do that?

For context

```
    let responce = await axios.get(`${api url}`)
    let upccode = ccode.toLocaleUpperCase()
    let bitcoinval = responce.data.bpi.USD.rate
    let bitcoin = bitcoinval
    return bitcoin
```

It is for a discord bot. I need it to return for more styling to become an embed for discord so that's that, and thanks to the people that help
edit:

in let bitcoinval = responce.data.bpi.USD.rate
the USD needs to be a var as it is what changes in the json file

Comment: So you want to return `USD` and not `rate`?

Comment: What do you mean by _"USD needs to be a var"_?

Comment: bpi[CURRENCY] where CURRENCY='USD' for instance

Comment: so quirimmo, i should use response.data.bpi.[upccode].rate where the [] is a var right? sadly that dose not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an object where a key is variable's value, instead of the dot notation, you can use brackets like this: `response.data.bpi[variable].rate`.

Check out the snippet below:

```js
const data = {
  bpi: {
    USD: {
      rate: 5
    },
    GBP: {
      rate: 10
    },
    EUR: {
      rate: 15
    }
  }
}

let currency = 'USD'
console.log(currency, data.bpi[currency].rate)

currency = 'GBP'
console.log(currency, data.bpi[currency].rate)
```